# vagrant plugin vagrant-hostmanager Installation on windows 10

Tags: plugins, vagrant-windows

I am trying to set up a testing env after following description https://github.com/OXID-eSales/oxvm_eshop
on a clean windows 10 pc

When I try to install the vagrant hostmanager, it seems that he is installing it sucessfully but when I use vagrant up, it tells me again that the plugin is missing.

**Terminal:**

```
PS C:\projecte\oxvm_eshop> vagrant plugin install vagrant-hostmanager
Installing the 'vagrant-hostmanager' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Installed the plugin 'vagrant-hostmanager (1.8.9)'!
PS C:\projecte\oxvm_eshop> vagrant up
Plugin 'vagrant-hostmanager' not found. Please install it using 'vagrant plugin install vagrant-hostmanager'.
```

Do you know what I have to change to have the installation working??

**Answer for Linux**
apparently running sudo

```
rm -Rf ~/.vagrant.d/gems/ && sudo rm ~/.vagrant.d/plugins.json
```

and then try and reinstall vagrant plugin install vagrant-hostmanager will do the trick.
However I dont know how to reform this script so it works on windows

Answer (score 0):

This apparently does not work with the newer versions of vagrant 2.1.4 and 2.1.3
downgrading to 2.1.2 fixed this issue

Comment: Are you still having this issue? I just tested Windows 10 + vagrant 2.1.5 and it worked just fine.

Comment: have not tested with 2.1.5 but that was the answer I got in vagrant git repro. I will test when I have time.

Comment: in 2.1.5 the issue is no longer persisting